# media query paragraph is not showing on entire mobile's screen width

Tags: html, css, media-queries, web-frontend

Problem: So my problem is pretty straight forward . I want to display my paragraph on the entire mobile screen's width what should I do
Here have a look on a problem that I am facing https://ibb.co/VvtRx1H.
I just want to display the paragraph that is enclosed in a red border on entire mobile screen

My CSS code:

```
   *{
    margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing: border-box;
   
}

h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent{
    width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-self: center;
}
.daughter{
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
}
.daughter img{
    width:450px;
}
.son{
    width:50%;
    padding:0 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-align: justify;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    h1{
        color:red;
    }
    .parent{
        display: block;
    }
    .daughter{
        width:100%;
    }
    .son{
        width:100%;
    }
}
@media (max-width:468px){
    .daughter img{
        padding:10%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width:410px){
    .daughter img{
        padding:10%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .son{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    
}
```

my HTML code:

```
<body>
<h1>My WEBSITE</h1>
<br>
<div class="parent">
    <br>
    <div class="son">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore minima doloremque aliquid ad voluptates iste dicta officiis repellat nesciunt a.</p>
        <br>

    </div>
    <div class="daughter">
        <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="image">

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edits needed to fix the problem:
Line 55, Css code.

```css
@media (max-width:410px){
    .daughter img{
        padding:10%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .son{
        border:1px solid red;
        height: 85vh;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .son p{
        height: 95%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: using your answer I got an output like this https://ibb.co/PhP6vLY. I am not sure why you have added extra height while the aim is to align the text horizontically on the mobile's screen. Adding more height will just ruin the entire display for the UI

Answer (score 0):

Apply meta tag in your head section

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Replace Style

```
*{
    margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing: border-box;
   
}

h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent{
    width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-self: center;
}
.daughter{
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
}
.daughter img{
    width:450px;
}
.son{
    width:50%;
    padding:0 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1{
        color:red;
    }
    .parent{
        display: block;
    }
    .daughter{
        width:100% !important;
    }
    .son{
        width:100%;
    }
    .parent{display: inline;}
}
@media (max-width:468px){
    .daughter img{
        padding:10%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width:410px){
    .daughter img{
        padding:10%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .son{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    
}
```

and html

```
<h1>My WEBSITE</h1>
<br>
<div class="parent">
    <br>
    <div class="son">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore minima doloremque aliquid ad voluptates iste dicta officiis repellat nesciunt a.</p>
        <br>

    </div>
    <div class="daughter">
        <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="image">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Still not working and do not worry about the meta tag I have included all the essential files correctly. I am facing problem as when the mobile pixel comes near 430px